# no match for 'operator==' in C++

Tags: c++

I'm writing a program that has a operator == overload method in the header file, as so:

```
bool Student::operator == (string sName){

 if(this->name==sName){
    return true;
 }else{
    return false;
 }
}
```

Student is a class in this case, with two parameters: a string called "name" and a double called "GPA"

The program in general uses a vector of Students, and lets you add, remove, and sort them by ABC order or by GPA.

For context, this is the student-remove method

```
void removeStudent(string rName, double rGPA){
Student removeStudent(rName, rGPA);//this will make a Student object with same values as the object to be removeS
for(int i = 0; i < roster.size(); i++){
    if(roster[i]==removeStudent){
        roster.erase(i);
 }
}}
```

and the name-sort method, which has its own helper method. It is supposed to sort names in ABC order, so A-names would be before F-names, and Z-names would be after said F-names. For example.

```
bool sortNameHelper(Student one, Student two){
if(one.getName()<two.getName()){
    return false; //if One's name is after Two's name in the ABC order
}else{
    return true; //if One's name is before Two's name in the ABC order
}}

void sortName(vector<Student> theList){
vector<Student> ABCList;
for(int i = 0; i < theList.size(); i++){
    if(theList[i+1]!=NULL){
        if(sortNameHelper(theList[i],theList[i+1])=false){
            //i's GPA is lesser than i+1's GPA
            //this means that i+1 must be placed before i in the new vector
            ABCList[i]=theList[i+1];
            ABCList[i+1]=theList[i];
        }else{
            //i's GPA is greater than or equal to i+1's GPA
            //this means that i will be placed before i+1 in the new vector
            ABCList[i]=theList[i];
            ABCList[i+1]=newList[i+1];
        }
    }
}
roster = ABCList;}
```

Both of these rely on the operator == being overloaded, so when I tried to run them, I get this error:

error: no match for ‘operator==’ (operand types are ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits >::value_type {aka Student}’ and ‘Student’)

I'm confused as to how to approach this issue. I figure that the operator == method needs to be rewritten, but doing strcmp(this->name,sName) crashes the compiler.

Comment: Looks like you only implemented `operator==(Student,std::string)` -- but you have to provide a [mre] (please read that link).

Comment: Do you have `bool Student::operator == (const Student& other) const`? The compiler says it can't find one. And it is much better pass arguments by const reference in such cases to avoid copying. And the operator itself should be const. Otherwise you are likely to have more error messages.

Comment: Yep, the types gotta match. If you make a `==` operator that takes a `Student` and a `string`, you have to supply a `Student` and a `string`. Doing anything else is like trying to fuel a gasoline engine with Coca Cola: It's not going to work.

Comment: The signature should generally be `bool Student::operator == (const Student& rhs) const { ... }`

Comment: The error message is quite clear: the actual arguments are `std::string` and `Student` (in this order). You have to implement `friend bool operator==(const std::string&, const Student&)`.